# How may I uninstall the "ps" (process status) utility on a *nix system?

Tags: security, command-history, ps

I have heard that `ps` (process status) can store users' commands history, like what shell history does.

Source: [comment on StackOverflow](https://serverfault.com/questions/48769/avoid-to-keep-command-in-history#comment1255394_48769),

> Note that if the goal is to hide passwords in command line arguments, they'll still be visible through ps –
> Benitok
> Apr 27, 2019 at 3:50

This seems to be a security risk.

Question:

- **Is it possible to clear the `ps` history, and how?**

Or, if that's not possible,

- **How may I uninstall, remove or disable the `ps` utility?**

Comment: The `ps` utility does not store the user's command history. It displays the status of currently running processes. That status is not stored by `ps` but tracked by the kernel. Removing `ps` not make any system more secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ps` doesn't store anything, but it does allow you to see all running processes on the system, which could be stored.  Removing the `ps` utility doesn't fix the problem, as the data is still available from the kernel to userspace.

On Linux, this information is provide via the virtual /proc filesystem has an option called `hidepid` which will allow you to prevent users from seeing processes that don't belong to them.  mounting with hidepid=2 will allow users to still use `ps`, but they will not be able to see any processes other than their own.

See here for more details:

https://linux-audit.com/linux-system-hardening-adding-hidepid-to-proc/

NetBSD has an option called `security.curtain`, which has a similar effect.  On freebsd the tunable is called `security.bsd.see_other_uids`.

As for the security implications.  developers on unix are taught to not encode sensitive information in process command line arguments, as they can be seen by others.   However hiding process information can be annoying, especially on a system with limited resources and multiple users not being able to examine who and what is using all the cpu/memory.  If you go down this route you probable want to create per user "temp" directories, as that can expose information as well.

(nice username)

Comment: The user made a point of saying "*nix", and the question was originally tagged with the [tag:FreeBSD] tag...

Comment: @Kusalananda Good point.  I've highlighted where the information is specific to Linux.  I tested security.curtain on netbsd.  it doesn't work on freebsd 13.1, even though it is in their man pages.  I guess this doesn't come up often.